# jquery not calling php using $.post

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a jquery that gets called when a checkbox is clicked. The jquery executes, however the PHP file isn't being called (at least I don't think it's being called).

I can't put "echo" statements in the PHP function since nothing is returned from PHP (it just updates a table when called by jquery) + I don't know where it would echo too!

1. Can someone tell me why the PHP function isn't being called?
2. How do I "debug" a PHP function being called this way through jquery assuming I can't just echo out variables?

The jquery:

```
$('#notify_checkbox').click(function(){

if($('#notify_checkbox').is(':checked'))
    {
        $.post("/upic/update_notify", { checked: "y", email: "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('email');?>" });
        $( "#notifyresult" ).html( "<p>Awesome, we'll send you an email!</p>" );
}
else
{
        $.post("/upic/update_notify", { checked: "n", email: "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('email');?>" });
        $( "#notifyresult" ).html( "<p>Okay, we won't email you.</p>" );
}
});
```

And the PHP (I'm using the CodeIgniter framework):

```
function update_notify()
{
    // Passed through AJAX
    $notify = $_POST['checked'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $this->load->model('musers');
    $query = $this->musers->update_user_notify($email, $notify);
}
```

EDIT: Using the full URL (http://.../upic/update_notify) in the $.post works. But calling just the controller and the function does not.

Comment: Install firebug and see what actually has happened

Comment: Damn jQuery, it never calls anymore... :P

Comment: wrap your click function in a document ready call otherwise it'll never be attached... that is `$(function(){   ...your javascript here... });`

Answer (score 0):

I find using log_message useful when doing debugging with CodeIgniter, take a look here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Apart from that, why do you think that the action is not being called?

Comment: Hey Freeat... good point, but this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You better to use:

```
$.post('<?=site_url('controller/function');?>',{data here})
```